# Pegar ceros "0" al inicio de número, si es menor a "10" en R

Tags: r, condiciones

Quisiera solicitar su ayuda. Estoy buscando pegar en mi columna de semana un cero "0" (literalmente el número cero) al inicio de cada valor, siempre y cuando este sea menor a 10. Esto, porque necesito sacarla fecha con el paquete "ISOweek", en particular la función "ISOweek2date", para ello, los argumentos que necesita es el año y la semana, pero si es menor a 10 el valor de la misma, debe tener un cero antes, por ejemplo, la semana 6 debería ser "06" y, en particular con esta función, deberá leerse como "W06" para que arroje la fecha solicitada.
Mi df:

```
df <- tibble(
  cliente = sample(c("Cliente del Oeste", "Cliente del Este"), 
                   size = 10, 
                   replace = T),
  alias = str_extract(cliente,"(\\w+)$"),
  semana = sample(x = 1:10, size = 10, replace = T),
  año = sample(c("2020","2021"), size = 10, replace = T),
  ventas = sample( x = 50:100, size = 10, replace = T))

# A tibble: 10 x 5
   cliente           alias semana año   ventas
   <chr>             <chr>  <int> <chr>  <int>
 1 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      2 2020      82
 2 Cliente del Este  Este       2 2021      54
 3 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      1 2020      52
 4 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      4 2020      52
 5 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      1 2021      95
 6 Cliente del Este  Este       7 2021      77
 7 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      1 2020      67
 8 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      8 2020      86
 9 Cliente del Este  Este       5 2021      63
10 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      6 2020      84
```

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más eficiente:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2021)  #Para datos reproducibles.
df <- tibble(
  cliente = sample(c("Cliente del Oeste", "Cliente del Este"), 
                   size = 10, 
                   replace = T),
  alias = str_extract(cliente,"(\\w+)$"),
  semana = sample(x = 1:10, size = 10, replace = T),
  año = sample(c("2020","2021"), size = 10, replace = T),
  ventas = sample( x = 50:100, size = 10, replace = T))


df
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   cliente           alias semana año   ventas
   <chr>             <chr>  <int> <chr>  <int>
 1 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      6 2021      54
 2 Cliente del Este  Este       5 2020      58
 3 Cliente del Este  Este       7 2021      87
 4 Cliente del Este  Este       9 2020      67
 5 Cliente del Oeste Oeste      7 2021      92
 6 Cliente del Este  Este       3 2021      99
 7 Cliente del Este  Este       2 2020      55
 8 Cliente del Este  Este       3 2021      71
 9 Cliente del Este  Este       8 2020      55
10 Cliente del Este  Este      10 2021      64
```

La columna semana es numérica, en la fila 10 tienes dos dígitos, en las demás tiene solo uno.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(semana = sprintf("W%02d", semana))

 # A tibble: 10 x 5
   cliente           alias semana año   ventas
   <chr>             <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int>
 1 Cliente del Oeste Oeste W06    2021      54
 2 Cliente del Este  Este  W05    2020      58
 3 Cliente del Este  Este  W07    2021      87
 4 Cliente del Este  Este  W09    2020      67
 5 Cliente del Oeste Oeste W07    2021      92
 6 Cliente del Este  Este  W03    2021      99
 7 Cliente del Este  Este  W02    2020      55
 8 Cliente del Este  Este  W03    2021      71
 9 Cliente del Este  Este  W08    2020      55
10 Cliente del Este  Este  W10    2021      64
```

Ahora la columna `semana` siempre comienza con `W` y el número que lo sigue está normalizado a largo 2, rellenando con ceros cuando hace falta. Es el del tipo caracter, no sería posible poner un cero a la izquierda y una `W` en el tipo `integer`.

`sprintf()` es una función complicada, porque es un wrapper de una función de `C`. Tiene, digamos, su propio lenguaje, tipo las expresiones regulares. En este caso el `2` después del `%0` indica el largo final de la cadena de caracteres. Si fuera un 3 entonces rellenaría con 0 a la izquierda hasta que el número tuviera tres posiciones: `001`, `010` y así.

La `W` que está antes es una cadena de caracteres arbitraria. En este caso puse `W` porque es lo que necesitará `ISOweek`. Es independiente de la formateo de los números. Lo comento porque es útil, se podría poner un signo `$`, un porcentaje con `%%` (doble para escaparlo), etc. Es buenísima para formatear números, pero se me complica la sintaxis, así que tengo siempre a mano un par de ejemplos que adapto para este tipo de cosas. Es súper eficiente.

Alternativamente:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(semana = ifelse(nchar(semana) == 1, #Corregido aquí
         paste0("W0", semana), 
         paste0("W", semana)))
```

Si no está usando `dplyr()` podrías usar:

```
df$semana <- sprintf("W%02d", df$semana)
```

Y de esa forma modificas la columna.

Esta opción es más enredada, pero más simple entender lo que hacer. si el número de caracteres se semana es igual a 1 le pega "W1", si no le pega solamente "W". En tu caso funciona bien porque tenés solamente dos largos posibles en la cadena de caracteres  `semana`, son 1 o 2 dígitos. Pero si tuvieras que normalizar largos muy desiguales tendrías que anidar condicionales.

> PD: ahora funciona, en la versión anterior estaba mal ubicado un paréntesis en el `ifelse`.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @mpaladino! Te agradezco muchísmo la ayuda y disculpa la demora de mi respuesta. He estado tratado algunas soluciones y ahora probé lo que me comentas. En la primera solución que me comentas: "df %>% 
  mutate(semana = sprintf("W%02d", semana))" jala de maravilla, solo que debo meterlo a un objeto, ya que por sí mismo no me hace la modificación como tal en la columna. Solo me queda duda en cuanto a que significa poner "02" después del %, es decir, la logica es como decir, "pon "W" y "0" si es menor a dos la longitud del número?

Comment: Con respecto a la segunda solución que me ayudaste df %>% 
  mutate(semana = ifelse(nchar(semana == 1), 
         paste0("W0", semana), 
         paste0("W", semana))); no me está funcionado =/. No sé porque no me deja pegarte una imagen de como se ve el resultado, pero digamos que no hace la distición entre la longitud de la celda, y a todos les pone "W0" antes del número, sin importar si es del 1-9 o mayores a 9 en la semana =/. Ya intenté modificarlo, pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien la lógica que tendría que ser para que agarre bien la función

Comment: La "solución" que había intentado y veo que también jala es:::::: test1['semanatest'] <- NA


for (i in 1:nrow(test1)) {
  if (test1$semana[i] < 10) {
    
    test1$semanatest[i] <- paste("0",test1$semana[i], sep = "")
  }
    else{
      test1$semanatest[i] <- test1$semana[i]
    }
}                           ## se que no es nada eficiente, ya que va de uno por uno poniendo, pero la verdad es que igual estoy tratando de verlo como "vectorizado" y, por lo tanto, son mil veces  mejor la solución que me dijiste. Tal vez porque aún no entiendo al 100 el "ifelse". Gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: El `ifelse()` que había puesto estaba mal, pero como lo estaba validando con un test mal hecho no me di cuenta. Una disculpa por si te confundí, ya está arreglado en la respuesta. `ifelse` es directamente vectorizada, no es necesario el bucle. Como el input es un vector automáticamente hace la operación en cada uno de los elementos de ese vector y regresa como output un vector del mismo largo. Lo mismo con `sprintf` y en general con todas las funciones de `R` que toman como input a un vector. La iteración explícita en necesaria solamente con objetos de la clase `list`.

Comment: esta respuesta debería marcarse como aceptada

Comment: @EmilioSaldaña si esta respuesta te ayudó, por favor, márcala como correcta para que se cierre: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas

Comment: Disculpa la demora @mpaladino, me cortaron el internet y hasta hoy me reanudaron la conexión. De nuevo, te agradezco mucho la ayuda y tu tiempo, en verdad!!! Y si, probé de nuevo la primera solución que proponías, considerando el ")" para "semana" y jala de maravilla; ya entendí cual era el tema. Gracias!!!

Comment: No hay problema! Me alegra que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Si es solo agregar un 0 cuando el valor es menor a 10:

```
df$semana<-ifelse(df$semana<10,paste0("0",df$semana),df$semana)
```

ojo que con esto tu columna semana pasa a ser de tipo character y no int.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Sandro! Te agradezco también mucho por la ayuda!! Y si, jala de maravilla también. Es como el que proponía @mpaladino en comentarios más arriba, pero me parece que la diferencia es que con tu solución, sería como tal el valor y no el número de caracteres. Me estoy metiendo más en este condicional vectorizado para entender y justo no hacerlo como tal en el loop de "celda por "celda". Gracias!!